# PHP Slim framework : No input file specified?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, slim

This is my directory structure

```
 
/path/www.mysite.com/
    public_html/ 
        api/
            v1/
                index.php
                .htaccess


.htaccess Rule : 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Issue :** 
    
When I navigate this url : http://technobuff.in/api/v1/hello this is not working. It shows **'No input file specified.'**
    but If I use this : http://technobuff.in/api/v1/index.php/hello this is working fine.

I am using Slim Framework for my API development. In localhost, This was working good. Please help and explain me about it little.

Comment: a quick glance.. noticed you had different [.htaccess for slim framework](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/example/.htaccess).

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks it worked for me.

Comment: glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Bagus Tesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4648586/bagus-tesa)

Just follow this link.
[.HTACCESS for Slim Framework](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/example/.htaccess)

Replace the content of .HTACCESS file with below content

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```